# Oracle Select to Make Month

Tags: string, oracle, date, select

I have the following select to take a filename that contains a timestamp and make it into the correct format for a Date/Time field, but when I use the TO_CHAR(TO_DATE... it causes my first and third substring to duplicate.  When I don't use the TO_CHAR(TO_DATE... it does not duplicate???

```
    SELECT 
SUBSTR(COMPARE_FILENAME, INSTR(FILENAME, 'e', 1) + 7, 2) ||'-'||
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(FILENAME, INSTR(FILENAME, 'e', 1) + 5, 2), 'MM')) ||'-'||
SUBSTR(FILENAME, INSTR(FILENAME, 'e', 1) + 1, 2) ||' '||
SUBSTR(FILENAME, INSTR(FILENAME, 'e', 1) + 9, 2) ||'.'||
SUBSTR(FILENAME, INSTR(FILENAME, 'e', 1) + 11, 2) ||'.'||
SUBSTR(FILENAME, INSTR(FILENAME, 'e', 1) + 13, 2) AS TIME
FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 1662;
```

The column I am selecting from has this: Name20200601225511.txt

It returns this: 01-01-JUN-20-20 22.55.11

Answer (score 1):

> take a filename that contains a timestamp and make it into the correct format for a Date/Time field

No need for this complicated string parsing logic. You can define a format specifier that contains literal parts, using double quotes.

This would properly parse your strings to `date`s:

```
to_date(filename, '"Name"YYYYMMDDHH24MISS".txt"')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ed797fcc54873635f58ef9bf20787b5)**:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
select to_date('Name20200601225511.txt', '"Name"YYYYMMDDHH24MISS".txt"') filedate from dual
```

```
| FILEDATE            |
| :------------------ |
| 2020-06-01 22:55:11 |
```

Comment: Thank you! That is working exactly how I want it to!

Comment: If it worked for you then you must accept the answer so that your question is marked as resolved.